# MATE menu is not configurable

Tags: linux, menuitem, linux-mint

I am using linux mint.
This is my Menu.
[image]
I am able to edit the menu under "Application". But I am not able to edit the menu under "Places" and "System". I would like to remove the "Package manager" and "Control panel" menu items under "System".

Is there a way to edit that menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 way.
You can edit menu System. Click right button on the button Menu, select option Preferences, panel System.

2 way.
Try edit configuration XML files in the directories:

- $HOME/.mateconf/apps/mintMenu/plugins/places
- $HOME/.mateconf/apps/mintMenu/plugins/system-management

Comment: Thanks. I use method one. It was easier.

Comment: WTF is "the button Menu?"

Answer (score 3):

I have personally discovered quite a few different "Check Boxes" are not de-selectable unless you run the menu editor as root. The only way I found to do this, is to open mate-terminal and type "sudo mozo" (the application name for the menu editor).

Comment: Thank you, the mozo program worked for me on Debian jessie with MATE. With alacarte, I could select and add items, but it had no effect.

Comment: mozo is the GUI answer even as of 2018